# removing linebreaks in python?

Tags: python, line-breaks

I'm working on a simple python game in which the player attempts to guess letters contained in a word. The problem is, when I print a word, it's printing the \n at the end.

From my initial research, I think I need to use r.string() to remove it. However, I'm not sure where it would go.

Sorry for the newbie question.

```
import random
with open('wordlist.txt') as wordList:
    secretWord = random.sample(list(wordList), 1)

print (secretWord)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The other answers are better in my opinion, but you can also use:

```
secretWord = secretWord.replace('\n', ''))
```

EDIT: OP stated secretWord is a list, not a string.

In the case of a list of strings, use:

```
secretWord = [each.replace('\n', '') for each in secretWord]
```

Comment: hmm, getting an error-- AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: Edited my original post for the use of lists.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `.strip()` to strip out whitespace:

```
secret_word = random.choice(wordList).strip()
```

Comment: thanks, but i'm getting an error--
TypeError: object of type '_io.TextIOWrapper' has no len()

Comment: hmm, getting a different error--

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: @JohnJamin: Use `list(wordList)` instead of `wordList` and it'll work.

Comment: secretWord = random.sample list(wordList.readlines(), 1).strip()

returns a syntax error...

Answer (score 1):

```
text = open("your file","r").read().replace('\n','')
x = set(text.split(" "))
```